# Returned data from post request not passed to vue template

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a returned data triggered by post request (method called `get_teams`) which is not passed to my vue template.could anyone advise what I did wrong? Am I not binding the data correctly to my vue template?

**app.js**

```
 var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        components: {
            teamsTableTemplate
        },
        data: {
            teams: null,
            editable: true,
            show_teams: false
        },
        methods: {
          get_teams : function(){
            this.reset_show('get_teams')
            $.post(js_local.ajaxurl,{
                action:'get_advisor_teams'
            }).done(function(data){
                this.teams = data
                this.show_teams = true
                console.log(this.teams)
            }).fail(function(data){
                console.log('fail @ { action : get_advisory_teams }')
            })

          }
        }
 })
```

**teams-table-template.js**

```
const teamsTableTemplate = {
template:
`
<table class="table tablesorter">
    <thead class="text-primary">
        <tr></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="">
        <tr v-for="team in teams">
            <td>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label for="69cd1dbb353338" class="form-check-label">
                        <input id="69cd1dbb353338" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"><span class="form-check-sign"></span>
                        <!---->
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="title">{{team.team_name}}</p>
                <p class="text-muted">{{team.problem_statement_text}}</p>
            </td>
            <td class="td-actions text-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                    <!----><i class="tim-icons icon-pencil"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
`,
props: ['teams','edit'],
data() {
    return {
    }
}
```

}

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
    <button @click="get_teams"></button>
    <teams-table-template :teams="teams" :edit="editable" v-if="show_teams" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can't find where you are calling `get_teams` method in your component... Please, create a working codepen or like that. It will help us help you.

Comment: If you have any idea of vue then I must tell you reactivity of the template depends upon the data property or a computed property if you want to use a value from a api make use of vuex instead and store the value you want to use in store or else if you want to call the api from the template only and store the response then make a local variable in data property of the template and use it it will be reactive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `this` is not your component instance inside .done() callback since you are using simple function. Maybe use arrow function.

Try changing:

```js
get_teams() {
        this.reset_show('get_teams')
        $.post(js_local.ajaxurl,{
            action:'get_advisor_teams'
        }).done((data) => {            // use arrow function
            this.teams = data
            this.show_teams = true
            console.log(this.teams)
        }).fail(function(data){
            console.log('fail @ { action : get_advisory_teams }')
        })

      }

// also make sure get_teams() method is invoking from somewhere else
created() {
  this.get_teams();
}
```

Comment: What is the get_items()?

Comment: get_items() -> get_teams(), typo

Comment: my v-for in my template is not outputting the right data. For example, {{text}} stays as {{text}}

Comment: can you share the code in where the output is not expected?

Comment: it is in the `teams-table-template.js` and the objects is `teams = 
[{"cohort":"Cohort 2019","project_id":"405","team_id":"1125","team_name":" Emily Doiafaf","problem_statement_text":"aslfnaksnfkjsbfkj","connector_id":"41"},{"cohort":"Cohort 2019","project_id":"413","team_id":"1133","team_name":"White FridayABS","problem_statement_text":"return return return","connector_id":"41"},{"cohort":"Cohort 2020","project_id":"422","team_id":"1142","team_name":"TEST 2020","problem_statement_text":"AHAHAHAHHAHA","connector_id":"41"}]` for example.

Comment: seems ok, do you see any error in console? also it will be great help if you share a working code-pen/jsFiddle else.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I realized I did not use JSON.parse for the returned data. That was causing me a lot of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using a callback like you're doing will cause some errors, so i recommend to use arrow functions `()=>{...}` instead of `function(){...}` as callback since you're loosing the context of `this` :

```
get_teams : function(){
    this.reset_show('get_teams')
    $.post(js_local.ajaxurl,{
        action:'get_advisor_teams'
    }).done((data) => {
        this.teams = data
        this.show_teams = true
        console.log(this.teams)
    }).fail(function(data){
        console.log('fail @ { action : get_advisory_teams }')
    })

  }
```

or by assigning `this` to a global variable called `that` and use it inside the callback context :

```
      get_teams : function(){
        this.reset_show('get_teams')
        let that=this; 
        $.post(js_local.ajaxurl,{
            action:'get_advisor_teams'
        }).done(function(data){
            that.teams = data
            that.show_teams = true
            console.log(that.teams)
        }).fail(function(data){
            console.log('fail @ { action : get_advisory_teams }')
        })

      }
```

Comment: my v-for in my template is not outputting the right data. For example, {{text}} stays as {{text}}

Comment: your component or vue instance are not registered correctly